# Publish orchard Contents Item from master site

Tags: orchardcms, multi-tenant

say I am trying to publish an article to a tenant from my main orchard site. how would i go about creating a module where i can select the content i want to publish and then publish it to the tenant I want. would I use xmlrpc  to post to it or is there another method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is already done.

See http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2VpIOjSJwFo&feature=share&list=PL49EB89430968C7D4 for a demo, and http://orchard.codeplex.com/discussions/402151 for the discussion of the feature. This is most likely going to be in 1.7.

Comment: I downloaded the fork but there has been a lot of issues with is that are way above my current programming knowledge. would you happen to know of a working version of this code and how i may acquire it?